# Why does my code only display 1 conversion output?

Tags: java

I am trying to find a mistake in my code. My code makes the user input several dollar amount and currency to where to convert. My code only display the output of the last input.

```
 for(i=0;i<=many;i++)
 {
 arrlist[i]= sc.nextLine();
 Temp = arrlist[i].split(" ");
 }

       for(i=0,j=1;i<=Temp.length;i+=2,j+=2){
           if(Temp[j].equals("PHP")){
               conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp[i])*51.23;
               System.out.println("\n$"+Temp[i]+" CONVERTS TO "+conversion+" PHP.");
           }
           if(Temp[j].equals("POUNDS")){
               conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp[i])*0.84;
               System.out.println("\n$"+Temp[i]+" CONVERTS TO "+conversion+" POUNDS.");
            }
           if(Temp[j].equals("LIRA")){
               conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp[i])*2040;
               System.out.println("\n$"+Temp[i]+" CONVERTS TO "+conversion+" LIRA.");
           }
           if(Temp[j].equals("FRANCS")){
               conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp[i])*9.85;
               System.out.println("\n$"+Temp[i]+" CONVERTS TO "+conversion+" FRANCS.");
           }
           if(Temp[j].equals("MARKS")){
               conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp[i])*3.23;
               System.out.println("\n$"+Temp[i]+" CONVERTS TO "+conversion+" MARKS.");
           }
           if(Temp[j].equals("YEN")){
               conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp[i])*260;
               System.out.println("\n$"+Temp[i]+" CONVERTS TO "+conversion+" YEN.");
           }

}
```

Output:

```
Please input first the dollar amount and besides it the currency where to 
convert
1 PHP
3 YEN
24 MARKS
53 LIRA

$53 CONVERTS TO 108120.0 LIRA.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 
Index 3 out of bounds for length 2
at CurrencyScanner.main(CurrencyScanner.java:32)
```

Comment: Valid array indices are `0` to `array.length - 1`. You are using `1` and `array.length`

Comment: What is the point of assigning to `Temp` in a loop, so it only has the value of the last element processed? If you just want the last, why have a loop?

Comment: following on what @ElliottFrisch said, I think i<=Temp.length should be j<Temp.length

Comment: i swap it with j, still the same wrong output

Comment: @Andreas, i dont need only the last. as you can see there are 4 inputs but only 1 output occurs which is the output of the last input. I need all inputs to have an output.

Comment: but the swap made the runtime error go away? The point@Andreas is making is you need something like Temp,addAll(sc.nextLine().split(" ")); as the only line in your first for loop. Temp = loses everything you have already put in and just saves the newest line.

Answer (score 1):

To make your example work I set *many* to be 3, but really you might prefer some kind of `while (sc.hasNextLine())` loop.

I also declared your Temp as an ArrayList:

```
ArrayList<String> Temp = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then the values get into Temp as follows:

```
for(i=0;i<=many;i++)
    {
        for (String linePart : sc.nextLine().split(" ")){
            Temp.add(linePart);}
    }
```

The above was important, because in your code each split array was replacing the preceding one.

To avoid looking beyond the end of the array, we needed:

```
for(i=0,j=1;j<Temp.size();i+=2,j+=2)
```

I needed `size()` rather than `length` because Temp is now an ArrayList.
The body of the for loop is pretty much unchanged except `[i]` becomes `.get(i)` and similarly for j.

Your code may vary a little, but all together it looks something like the below:

```
{

    ArrayList<String> Temp = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
    int i;
    int j;
    int many=3;
    Double conversion;

    for(i=0;i<=many;i++)
    {
        for (String linePart : sc.nextLine().split(" ")){
            Temp.add(linePart);}
    }

    for(i=0,j=1;j<Temp.size();i+=2,j+=2){
        if(Temp.get(j).equals("PHP")){
            conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp.get(i))*51.23;
            System.out.println("\n$"+Temp.get(i)+" CONVERTS TO "+conversion+" PHP.");
        }
        if(Temp.get(j).equals("POUNDS")){
            conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp.get(i))*0.84;
            System.out.println("\n$"+Temp.get(i)+" CONVERTS TO "+conversion+" POUNDS.");
        }
        if(Temp.get(j).equals("LIRA")){
            conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp.get(i))*2040;
            System.out.println("\n$"+Temp.get(i)+" CONVERTS TO "+conversion+" LIRA.");
        }
        if(Temp.get(j).equals("FRANCS")){
            conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp.get(i))*9.85;
            System.out.println("\n$"+Temp.get(i)+" CONVERTS TO "+conversion+" FRANCS.");
        }
        if(Temp.get(j).equals("MARKS")){
            conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp.get(i))*3.23;
            System.out.println("\n$"+Temp.get(i)+" CONVERTS TO "+conversion+" MARKS.");
        }
        if(Temp.get(j).equals("YEN")){
            conversion = Double.parseDouble(Temp.get(i))*260;
            System.out.println("\n$"+Temp.get(i)+" CONVERTS TO "+conversion+" YEN.");
        }

    }
}
```

which for input:

```
1 PHP
3 YEN
24 MARKS
53 LIRA
```

yields

$1 CONVERTS TO 51.23 PHP.

$3 CONVERTS TO 780.0 YEN.

$24 CONVERTS TO 77.52 MARKS.

$53 CONVERTS TO 108120.0 LIRA.